# Pagination on a List of HashMap

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I want to paginate a long list that consists of `HashMap<String, String>`. Each HashMap contains of title, date and description.

Most of the examples for pagination that I have come across on StackOverflow or on various online tutorials, involve use of tables. However, I do not want to put the above data in a table.

Currently I am displaying the list using the following jsp code.

```
<div id="content">
    <c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
        <h3 class="title">
            <c:out value="${item.title}" />
        </h3>
        <h3 class="subtitle">
            <c:out value="${item.date}" />
        </h3>
        <p class="text">
            <c:out value="${item.description}" />
        </p>
    </c:forEach>
</div>
```

I want to splice the list and paginate it appropriately in the above format. The list generally consists of around 80-100 records. Also, there is no backend database. This list is being generated dynamically.

I don't want to implement it in pure JavaScript. I am looking for a solution in JQuery. However, I am not sure if there exists a good JQuery Plugin that would help me with this task.

Any suggestions on how to go ahead with this ?

Thanks!

Comment: I was able to paginate this list by using a hack. I don't know if this the right way. I created an <ul> and embedded all child tags inside a single <li>. I then used the regular pagination technique on the resulting lists. Works well !